# Creating an H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator instance from existing coefficients

Tags: python, h2o

I have a set of coefficients from a trained model but I don't have access to the model itself or training dataset. I'd like to create an instance of `H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator` and set the coefficients manually to use the model for prediction.

The first thing I tried was (this is an example to reproduce the error):

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
from h2o.frame import H2OFrame
h2o.init()

# creating some test dataset
test = {"x":[0,1,2], "y":[0,0,1]}
df = H2OFrame(python_obj=test)
glm = H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family='binomial', model_id='logreg')
# setting the coefficients
glm.coef = {'Intercept':0, 'x':1}
# predict
glm.predict(test_data=df)
```

This throws an error:

> H2OResponseError: Server error
>   water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException:   Error: Object
>   'logreg' not found in function: predict for argument: model

I also tried to set `glm.params` keys based on the keys of a similar trained model:

```
for key in trained.params.keys():
    glm.params.__setitem__(key, trained.params[key])
```

but this doesn't populate `glm.params` (`glm.params = {}`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use the function [makeGLMModel](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html?#h2o.estimators.glm.H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator.makeGLMModel)

This is further described in the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#modifying-or-creating-a-custom-glm-model), and I will repost here for your convenience:

**Modifying or Creating a Custom GLM Model**

In R and python, the `makeGLMModel` call can be used to create an H2O model from given coefficients. It needs a source GLM model trained on the same dataset to extract the dataset information. To make a custom GLM model from R or python:

- R: call `h2o.makeGLMModel`. This takes a model, a vector of coefficients, and (optional) decision threshold as parameters.
- Pyton: `H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator.makeGLMModel` (static method) takes a model, a dictionary containing coefficients, and (optional) decision threshold as parameters.